# Generating REST API documentation based Java code split by user role

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I have some endpoints in my REST API (Java + Spring Boot under the hood). I am using SpringFox with Swagger-UI do have some documentation. But I have a problem now. I would like to show for endpoints for user related to his role.

So, for example, some user with `role A` should see only `/endpoint-A1` and `/endpoint-A2` and user with `role B` should see only `/endpoint-B1` and `/endpoint-B2`, and `admin role` should see all the endpoints.

As far as I researched, it is not an option to achieve this with SpringFox. And I understand that because there is no place to interact between Spring Security and SpringFox on this field. Correct me if I'm wrong.

But I thought maybe you know an option, to use Spring Boot code and generate the documentation bases on it and export it somewhere - I do not need to host it as SpringFox is doing. I only need to have this generated to separate files based on user roles. Later I will manage the user roles somehow. Do you know such a tool? Or maybe you have any idea how to achieve that in another way?

Comment: You can use TAGs to categorize api endpoints docs in swagger.

Comment: Yep, and what next?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering for API parts in swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935041/filtering-for-api-parts-in-swagger)

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [list the api in swagger based on user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904213/list-the-api-in-swagger-based-on-user-roles/63246343) You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63246343/6465520)